# How to fix an error using a colorscheme for gvim?

Tags: colors, vim, gvim

**My vim directory:**

```
>:/usr/share/vim$ ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2010-09-26 00:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 352 root root 12288 2010-09-25 14:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 2010-09-25 14:35 addons
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    15 2010-09-25 14:35 gvimrc -> /etc/vim/gvimrc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 2010-09-25 14:35 registry
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  4096 2010-09-25 14:35 vim72
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     5 2010-09-25 14:35 vimcurrent -> vim72
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 2010-09-25 14:35 vimfiles -> /etc/vim
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 2010-09-25 14:35 vimrc -> /etc/vim/vimrc

>:/usr/share/vim$ ls vim72/colors
ron.vim  ir_black.vim  morning.vim  pablo.vim
```

vim runtimepath:

```
/usr/share/vim,/etc/vim
```

I have the following line in `/etc/vim/vimrc`

```
colorscheme ir_black
```

**Problem:**

As you can see above, I have `ir_black.vim` in the `/usr/share/vim/vim72/colors` directory. Even then, I get the below error when launching gvim and screen is just white (no color):

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vimrc:
line  100:
E185: Cannot find color scheme ir_black
```

**What I've done:**

```
>:/usr/share/vim$ sudo mkdir /usr/share/vim/colors && 
 sudo cp -R /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/* /usr/share/vim/colors
```

This got the colorscheme to work but my screen started looking very weird with gaps between each character.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to create and modify files in /usr.  Use ~/.vim, or /etc/vim if you really have multiple user accounts and want them all to have the same vim config.  This means putting color schemes in ~/.vim/colors/ or /etc/vim/colors/.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure about that error message but seems like your vimrc file cannot find your colorscheme.

Have you tried using color scheme from your home folder ?(`/home/your_home_folder/.vim/colors/ir_black.vim`)

If you have some colorscheme files in that folder then you can activate from `edit->ColorScheme->ir_black`. 
If you want "ir_black" as your default gvim cholorscheme put "colorscheme ir_black" in your vimrc file (`/home/your_home_folder/.vimrc`).

And the reason you are seeing lot of gap between each character is the font that you are using in your vimrc is not available in computer.